# React DayPicker Styling Placeholder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker

I am working with *react-day-picker* field (https://react-day-picker.js.org/). I want to customize it. I have already went to *react-day-picker/lib/style.css* and played with colors, font sizes etc. But the problem is, I can't change placeholder style itself! I have already tried everything, basically what I want to do is to display *"Hello"* and make the *red background* instead of *YYYY-M-D* and *white background*. Please, help. That's what I have right now: 
https://ibb.co/nGgCwJ

My **.js code**:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import DayPickerInput from 'react-day-picker/DayPickerInput';
import 'react-day-picker/lib/style.css';

class DateP extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleDayChange = this.handleDayChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      selectedDay: undefined
    };
  }
  handleDayChange(day) {
      this.setState({ selectedDay: day });
  }
  render() {
    const { selectedDay} = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {selectedDay && <h3>Day: {selectedDay.toLocaleDateString()}</h3>}
        {!selectedDay && <h3>Date Picker</h3>}
        <DayPickerInput
          onDayChange={this.handleDayChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DateP;
```

Comment: ?did you tried using `input[placeholder]`

Comment: @HarishSoni in React it doesn't work that way...

Comment: You can use CSS however.

Comment: Let me know if you need further help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I got for you.
Just opened the website gone to elements and edited those.

So if you want to achieve this just create a css file and import that into your CSS file.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can't open images. Can you upload them to ibb.co?

Comment: Yeah sure. These are the links https://ibb.co/cvoQYy
https://ibb.co/eqmZRJ

Comment: No problem buddy.

Answer (score 1):

In addition if you want to change the color of the placeholder text (the initial date) use this:

```
::placeholder { /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
  color: black;
  opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
}

:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
  color: red;
}

::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Microsoft Edge */
  color: red;
}
```

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_placeholder.asp

Comment: This was so helpful . Thank you !